# jQuery: Get text content from nearby element and print to modal title

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom

Using jQuery, how can I get the text content of a  element within the same div as the clicked  tag, then store that text content as a variable, and immediately print it to the title of a modal?

At the moment, the following code just fetches all six titles of each card and prints them all to the modal header. I've experimented with different functions like .closest(), .next(), and $(this) but I can't get it to work! I read somewhere about an array function using .eq() but I wasn't sure how to change the array number depending on which of the six  tags were clicked.

I can't produce the entire HTML and jQuery here, but I can place the relevant code snippets below:

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <h5 id="InsertTitle" class="modal-title"></h5>
</div
```

...

```
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header">
      <i onClick="add()" class="i-hover"></i>
      <h4 class="mb-0">Title</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="card-body">
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

...

```
function add() {
        var title = $('i.i-hover').next("h4").text();
        console.log(title);
        $("#InsertTitle.h5").text(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this

```
function add(el) {
    var title = $(el).next("h4").text();
    console.log(title);
    $("#InsertTitle.h5").text(title);
 }
```

And in html

```
<i onClick="add(this)" class="i-hover"></i>
```

> **Note:** by using `$(this)` directly in the function may not refer to the desired element .. so you can pass an argument for (this)

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, I will mark it as solved as soon as I can.

Comment: You're totally welcome @JamesWatson .. Have a great day :-)